# What happens if you used "rm -rf *" in /Users or /Users/someUser?

Tags: command-line, permission, macos

**Note: Don't type `rm` or any variation of it into terminal under any circumstances if you are not experienced with the command line**

Does the Mac OS X block you from using `rm` in those directories to delete a user or delete all the users and do you need to use sudo and put in an administrator password or does it let you without any passwords?

For example if you typed in the following line into terminal would it just completely wipe everything?

```
cd /Users; echo rm -rf *
```

Of course the echo wouldn't be used if you actually wanted the remove command to run.

Comment: We already have a question on `rm -rf /` in the root directory at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/stuck-on-blue-screen-after-running-rm-in - let's keep this to what happens when you `rm` in `/Users` directory...

Answer (score 1):

Two cases:

- you're logged in as **root**. Everything goes away.
- you're logged in as a normal user.  All of that user's files go away.

In some systems, `rm` is supposed to prompt you if you do this at the "/" level.  Do not count on that prompt.

With *El Capitan*, Apple supplies a "prompt" per se, which *by default* should leave enough of the operating system to boot and recover from your backups.  To see if this has not been disabled, use

```
csrutil status
```

Further reading:

- [How to Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in OS X El Capitan](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/)
- [Re: Backing up ACL's](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2005-02/1458.html)

Comment: This is mostly incorrect - SIP doesn't protect anything in /Users - only normal ACL and filesystem separations exist in that part of the filesystem.

Comment: You can recover the system if your home directory was erased (a little painful, of course).

Comment: Also - please note - the question did have `rm -rf /` in the body so this question was addressing that aspect before being migrated here. We cover `rm` at the root already at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/stuck-on-blue-screen-after-running-rm-in

Comment: I've had this conversation before, where it turned out that a minor change of command was sufficient to bypass the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will wipe everything and it wont work without the `sudo` privileges; You can try it in a virtual environment or 
you can take a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4fzInlyYQo
Have a nice Day !