# How to recover deleted directory (rm -rf *)

Tags: macos, backup, command-line

I have deleted a directory accidentally from terminal by using "rm -rf *" on Mac (Mac 11.6 big Sur). I don't have it backed up on other devices and Time Machine wasn't on. Is there any way to recover this directory? It contains a lot of important information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  In future, make backups.

Comment: Simply not reliably - if this is an SSD then really unlikely. Assume that data does not exist until you have a couple of backups. If a hard disk then you might be lucky with DiskWarrior - but first turn the machine off now and do not use it until you get DIskWarrior - and better boot off an external disk.

Comment: [What was your current working directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/174602/5472) when you deleted files?

Comment: wouldn't it be nice if by default user's cli `rm` actually just sent stuff to the trash, like deleting in finder

Comment: @theonlygusti if you want to use the unix command line then know what the commands do before hitting return or enter.

Comment: Let’s take the design discussion to chat. I removed the editorial from my answer - OP has a rough choice at this point.

Comment: @theonlygusti There are plenty of scripting solutions out there that will substitute for `rm` and move files to another location.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine uses APFS snapshots, so you want to be sure you don’t have a snapshot to restore things:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

You also want to stop all writes to the system until you’re ready to decide to do professional data recovery. Do you have an idea how much your data is worth? $10 or $100 or $1000

If you can afford to power it off and keep it off, you will have the best chance to run software that will look in free space and attempt to recover files - but without hard drive and older OS - this is less useful now than in the past.